# TFS2018 Document Libraries

Tags: tfs

What are people doing to for project portal connections/document libraries in TFS 2018 now that MS has removed the SharePoint Integration?  We had a TFS2013 environment that's been upgraded to 2018, but we're still trying to figure out what to do with the documents associated with the projects that used to be accessible via the "project portal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use Sharepoint. Just put a link to the Sharepoint portal in the team dashboard.

The only thing lost when the SP integration was deprecated were the Sharepoint dashboards, which were inferior to the dashboards already in TFS.

Comment: Duh.  Why didn't I think of that?  Thanks!